# Have to ask for "list" instead of "link." Typo in FQL API or do I misunderstand?

Tags: facebook-fql

First, **This is not a bug report!** I want to make sure this isn't a misunderstanding before I file a bug report (in the appropriate place).

```
SELECT post_id FROM like WHERE user_id = me() AND object_type = "link"
```

does not work, but

```
SELECT post_id FROM like WHERE user_id = me() AND object_type = "list"
```

returns the links that I have liked.

Am I misunderstanding something or has facebook made a horrible mistake?

Comment: +1 on this. I'm seeing the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook most likely made an error (a bug) as to this date the call with `list` no longer works

`SELECT object_id, post_id FROM like WHERE user_id = me() AND object_type = "link"`

is the correct call